# Adding a onclick event to a span -

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I am struck with adding a onclick function to my span - though it looks simple - I am sure - there is something I am missing

Please find the code sample below

```
https://jsbin.com/naqejanigu/edit?html,css,js,output
```

Comment: Capitalize the `B` in `document.getElementById()`. Look in your developer console (F12)

Comment: Jeez - thanks a lot - a stupid one on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function conv() {
  var cel = document.getElementbyId('unit');
  cel.innerHTML = 'F';
}

function conv() {
  var cel = document.getElementById('unit');
  cel.innerHTML = 'F';
}

getElementbyId should be getElementById.
```

[image]